# Wordpress Custom Menu - how to dynamically link to current user's page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

In the Wordpress Menus Custom Links, I want to create a page called "My Page", and when the Current User clicks this Custom Link, it takes him to his specific page.

E.g mydomain.com/%CURRENT USERNAME% /
    mydomain.com/johnsmith

Reading other posts, it appears that the Wordpress Custom Link understands only a static URL, not a dynamic one.

Therefore I need some way for the system to "get" the current user info, and redirect accordingly.

I have viewed the replies at [this previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869849/create-a-dynamic-site-address-in-a-wordpress-menu/17871723#17871723) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212154/adding-custom-menu-item-to-wordpress-menu) but I am still lost. 
My coding ability is even less than the first guy's (but I do try!), so I can understand the theory, but I don't understand the technical language.

Therefore, I understand "You need to place this code, in your Theme Functions/in the script of the page".
But I don't understand "You need to run a jQuery with this code"

1. What information can I enter in the Custom Link to achieve this?
2. What code do I need to enter in the back-end to read this information correctly?

Thank you very much.

Comment: It might be easier to add a manualy coded link into your menu before or after the wordpress generated menu. Usually a "my acccount" kind of link sits outside of the main nav anyways. Could this work for you? Or does it have to sit within a main menu? Because the correct way to do such a link properly requires delving into "walkers" and they are not a lot of fun.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Simon.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @SimonPollard  Ideally, this would sit within a main menu, so that user can view page X, page Y, and then easily click back to "My Page".         But I prefer doing things the correct way, I just don't know enough in order to know that there is another way.  So manually coded would be fine for me, but I would just need real baby step instructions about exactly where to place the code.  (For example, I don't know what a "walker" is, but I'm happy to learn).  Thanks

Comment: Hi - are you still after help with this?

Comment: Hello, yes please.  I am still after help for this.

Comment: Hi, do you cache you site at all? It makes a difference to the answer.